# Blackberry java app running in background

Tags: java, blackberry, close-application

I would like to exit the application with 2 different ways:
- When key "escape" pressed, the application exit but still run in background.
- When the user select "Close" in the menu to close the application totally. This is already working as it is the default behavior.

In my MainScreen class, I have overwritten the close() method that call super.close() at the end in order to close the screen.

Thank you

Comment: The question is: how to exit the application and keep it running in background?

My current application exit and does not stay in background.

I would like something like the Google Maps application. If you press the escape key the application is still running in background, if you use their menu "Exit" the application close completely and stop running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the method `Application.requestBackground()`

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#requestBackground()